# Using LD_PRELOAD on Fedora 25 causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, ld-preload

I have found a strange behavior while I was trying to use a library that I wrote a long time ago. The main problem is, when the program is executed on **Fedora 25** and linked to my library by using LD_PRELOAD, the system raises a Segmentation Fault. I've made a small sample of my old library to easily understand the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t size);

void *malloc(size_t size) 
{
  void *ptr = __libc_malloc(size);
  fprintf(stdout, "Malloc(%d)->(%p)\n", (int) size, ptr);
  return ptr;
}
```

This code was compiled by using these parameters:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -O3 -Wall -o libtest.o libtest.c
gcc -shared -o libtest.so libtest.o
```

The program was executed as follows:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so ./progtest
```

I found out that the "**fprintf**" line was causing the Segfault problem. So I've changed the "**stdout**" file descriptor to "**stderr**", and the problem was gone.

Then I tested the same code using the "**stdout**" file descriptor as output for "**fprintf**" on another machine running **CentOS 7**, and it worked fine in both cases using "**stdout**" and "**stderr**".

By observing these results, I wonder what I am missing and why this is happening.

GLibc and GCC versions installed on Fedora 25:

> GNU ld version 2.26.1-1.fc25
>
> gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)

GLibc and GCC versions installed on CentOS 7:

> GNU ld version 2.25.1-22.base.el7
>
> gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fprintf` itself may need to use `malloc` under some circumstances. One possible reason is that `stderr` is unbuffered while `stdout` is line buffered. `fprintf(stdout)` might have a buffer already, or it may try to allocate one, ending up calling your `malloc`, which calls into `fprintf` again, but it is not re-entrant on the same `FILE*`.

You can prevent re-entrancy with a flag, such as (C11):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <threads.h>
thread_local bool inside_malloc = false;
void *malloc(size_t size) {
    void *ptr = __libc_malloc(size);
    if (!inside_malloc) {
        inside_malloc = true;
        fprintf(stdout, "Malloc(%zd)->(%p)\n", size, ptr);
        inside_malloc = false;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Another approach is to ditch using fprintf, instead use snprintf to a local buffer and call write() to output the string made by snprintf

Comment: @nos That is likely to work, although I would still be wary that `snprintf` might involve allocations.